# Regex parse by commas

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to parse the log file below; however I am a bit stuck on figuring out how to parse it by commas.

```
NOTICE Failed-Attempt: EAP session timed out, ACSVersion=acs-1.6.0.10-B.153.x86_64, ConfigVersionId=100, UserName=username, NAS-IP-Address=10.10.10.10, Calling-Station-ID=0123.4a56.78b9, NAS-Port-Id=123, AcsSessionID=host/123/321, AuthenticationIdentityStore=AD1, AuthenticationMethod=AuthMethod, SelectedAccessService=Wireless, DetailedInfo=Invalid username or password specified\, Retry is  allowed, FailureReason=24421
```

I tried the following parse method, however it is not returning my intended results: (?:[^,]+)

The ideal goal is to match the following:

```
NOTICE Failed-Attempt: EAP session timed out
ACSVersion=acs-1.6.0.10-B.153.x86_64
UserName=username
NAS-IP-Address=10.10.10.10
Calling-Station-ID=0123.4a56.78b9
NAS-Port-Id=123
AcsSessionID=host/123/321
AuthenticationIdentityStore=AD1
AuthenticationMethod=AuthMethod
SelectedAccessService=Wireless
DetailedInfo=Invalid username or password specified, Retry is allowed
FailureReason=24421
```

Comment: `$explodedList = explode(',', $message);`

Comment: I think `preg_split('~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\K,~', $s)` might work for you. It matches only those commas that aren't escaped. It supports any amount of escaped backslashes before the unescaped comma.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, would it be possible to do it purely in regex?

Comment: Do you mean to use a regex in *`preg_match_all`*? Try `'~(?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\.)+~s'`. Mind the four backslashes. No idea if word boundaries work for you, I removed them for now.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, it seems to catch the commas between specified and Retry https://regex101.com/r/rYogFv/1

Comment: In my comments above, I posted the string literal to be used in PHP. The https://regex101.com/r/rYogFv/2 is the corresponding demo on regex101. Are you using PHP? Post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match any 1+ chars other than a comma and backslash, or any escape sequence using

```
/(?:[^\\,]|\\.)+/s
```

In PHP:

```
$regex = '~(?:[^\\,]|\\.)+~s';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYogFv/3).

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[^\\,]` - any char other than `\` and a comma
  - `|` - or
  - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any char including line break chars (due to the `s` modifier)
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat 1 or more times.

A more efficient version of the regex (assuming the match should start with a char other than whitespace and a comma):

```
/(?=[^,\s])[^\\,]*(?:\\.[^\\,]*)*/s
```

In PHP:

```
$regex = '/(?=[^,\s])[^\\\\,]*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\,]*)*/s';
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYogFv/4)

The `(?=[^,\s])` positive lookahead requires the char to the right to be any char but a `,` and whitespace, and `[^\\,]*(?:\\.[^\\,]*)*` is the unrolled equivalent of the regex explained above.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, this is exactly what I was looking for!